# Elm - Combining and sorting over multiple types

Tags: types, combinations, elm

The last week I'm experimenting with elm (so consider me a beginner) and was wondering about the following,

I have defined multiple types Foo and Bar for example both with a date field.

```
type alias Foo = 
{
    date : String,
    check : Bool
}
```

and

```
type alias Bar = 
{
    date : String,
    check : Bool,
    text : String
}
```

Is it possible to combine and sort both lists by using sort?([sort](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/List#sortBy)) 
I would like to do this to create one list to present all items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a union type that allows you to have a list that mixes both Foo and Bar:

```elm
type Combined
  = FooWrapper Foo
  | BarWrapper Bar
```

Now you can combine two lists of Foos and Bars, then use a `case` statement as the `sortBy` parameter:

```elm
combineAndSort : List Foo -> List Bar -> List Combined
combineAndSort foos bars =
  let
    combined =
      List.map FooWrapper foos ++ List.map BarWrapper bars
    sorter item =
      case item of
        FooWrapper foo -> foo.date
        BarWrapper bar -> bar.date
  in
    List.sortBy sorter combined
```

Comment: @Chad How do you change the order of the sort? From ascending to descending and vice versa?

Comment: @Stanko - you'll need to use [List.sortWith](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#sortWith), which is a more general purpose sorting function that allows you to change the ordering.